# 'sizeof(off_t) != 8' when compiling libfuse for android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, fuse

I'm trying to compile [libfuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) with NDK, my environment:

Win10(64bit) + NDK(r14b,64bit) + libfuse(3.1.0)

Error occurs in *fuse_common.h*, it checks size of `off_t`:

```
$ ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : fuse <= buffer.c
In file included from jni/../../libfuse/lib/buffer.c:15:
In file included from jni/../../libfuse/lib/fuse_i.h:9:
In file included from jni/../../libfuse/include\fuse.h:19:
jni/../../libfuse/include/fuse_common.h:745:13: error: bit-field
      '_fuse_off_t_must_be_64bit' has negative width (-1)
        { unsigned _fuse_off_t_must_be_64bit:((sizeof(off_t) == 8) ? 1 : -1); };
                   ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/fuse/__/__/libfuse/lib/buffer.o] Error 1
```

here's the check in *fuse_common.h*:

```
struct _fuse_off_t_must_be_64bit_dummy_struct \
    { unsigned _fuse_off_t_must_be_64bit:((sizeof(off_t) == 8) ? 1 : -1); };
```

I searched on google, there's `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` definition, which can be used to change the size of `off_t`, I have this defined my 'Android.mk' file:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    ....
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
    ....
```

And even add this line at the beginning of *fuse_common.h*

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

Still not working, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** Provided solution is much like workaround, see @Dan's answer for reliable and official way to get 64-bit `off_t`.

On Android `off_t` is always 32-bit length, and there is no preprocessor macro that controls its size. (Though it is true only for NDK development since modern bionic allow to configure `off_t` size at compile time). And because of this you cannot compile your library directly.

But I guess there is some way to workaround it. Android NDK offers non-POSIX extended type - `off64_t`, and also it provides a complementary set of library functions that accept it instead of `off_t`. They are distinguished by `64` suffix, i.e. `lseek64()`, `mmap64()`. So to make things work you may try to add global configuration header to your project:

```
/* let off_t to be a 64-bit length */
typedef off64_t off_t;

/* use appropriate versions of system functions */
/* list here only functions that have off_t parameters and are used by your library */
#define mmap mmap64
#define lseek lseek64
```

And of course keep in mind that compiled code now is linked against `*64()` functions instead of regular ones and any public interfaces expect `off64_t` instead of `off_t`.

Comment: The `typedef off64_t off_t;` conflicts with `<sys/types.h>`, I have to replace all the `off_t` to `off64_t` in the source code, at least it compiles now.

Comment: This is likely to cause bugs anywhere else an `off_t` is used, since it will be an `off64_t` that gets truncated to 32-bit for the kernel. Moreover, this answer is obsolete since `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` has been available in the NDK since r14 (though not really working until r15c).

Comment: Agree that my answer is obsolete. Also it would cause problems only if user missed to add functions to alias list and I've mentioned that all library public interfaces become `off64_t`-powered. Am I missing something? Don't get your point about truncating to 32-bit. If we pass `off64_t` to syscall that expects 32-bit `off_t` on 32-bit system we likely to break arg list at all since extra 32 bits replace register / stack slot that another parameter should use, effectively shifting positions for all subsequent arguments. So IMO it would be better to say that we have UB rather than truncating.

Comment: It's the "list all the `off_t` functions your library uses" that's troubling. That's incredibly error prone.

Answer (score 5):

Update to NDK r15c. `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` works from there on out.

Note that most `off64_t` system calls weren't available until android-21. If your `minSdkVersion` is set below that and you use `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, many functions will not be available.